# Detect duplicate object properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Based on a quick mockup like below I need to add URL route objects to an Array property in my app.

in the function below `addAppRoute(routeObbj)` I would like to add a check to see if the new route being added already exist or not in the property `this.cache.webDevAppRoutes`

How can I make sure duplicates are not added?  It would need to be based on a duplicate `module` and `action` being the same

```
var app = {
    cache: {
        webDevAppRoutes: [],
    },

    addAppRoute: function(route) {
        var routes = this.cache.webDevAppRoutes;
        routes.push(route);
    },

    getAppRoutes: function() {
        var routes = this.cache.webDevAppRoutes;
        console.log(routes);
    },

    addBookmarkAppRoutes: function() {

        this.addAppRoute({
            module: 'bookmarks',
            action: 'view',
            params: [{
                id: 123
            }],
        });

        this.addAppRoute({
            module: 'bookmarks',
            action: 'edit',
            params: [{
                id: 123
            }],
        });

        this.addAppRoute({
            module: 'bookmarks',
            action: 'add',
            params: [],
        });
    },

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through the array and check that it doesn't already have an entry with that `module` and `action`. You can use `Array#some`, for instance:

```
if (routes.some(function(r) { return r.module == route.module && r.action == route.action)) {
    // It's a duplicate
}
```

`Array#some` returns `true` as soon as a call to its callback returns a truthy value; otherwise, it returns `false`.

In ES2015, that's a bit more concise:

```
if (routes.some(r => r.module == route.module && r.action == route.action)) {
    // It's a duplicate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have a `Map` of already added routes:

```js
var webDevAppRoutes = new Map();


function addAppRoute(route) {
    var key = [route.module, route.action].join();

    if(!webDevAppRoutes.has(key))
        webDevAppRoutes.set(key, route);
}

addAppRoute({
    module: 'bookmarks',
    action: 'view',
    params: [{
        id: 123
    }],
});

addAppRoute({
    module: 'bookmarks',
    action: 'edit',
    params: [{
        id: 123
    }],
});

addAppRoute({
    module: 'bookmarks',
    action: 'add',
    params: [],
});

addAppRoute({
    module: 'bookmarks',
    action: 'add',
    params: 'once again',
});

console.log([...webDevAppRoutes.values()])
```

For ES5, find a polyfill or use a POJO instead of `Map`.

Comment: This is interesting and nice to see a new feature example usage.  I notice that `var webDevAppRoutes` no longer behaves like an array of objects.  Is there a way to use this to prevent duplicate routes being added to my array while still allowing me to access my object property as an array of objects?

Comment: @JasonDavis: look at the last line: `map.values()` gives you an iterator, and `[...map.values()]` is a normal array.